# Passing a type specifier to a template function

Tags: c++, templates

I am trying to replace a Macro in the form of

```
#define FOO(object, typeSpecifier) object.f<typeSpecifier>()
```

How can i write an equivalent template function that takes a type specifier to call `object.f<typeSpecifier>()` with?

I.e. pass a custom type with specifier `Mytype` and an object `object` to `f` like `f(object, MyType`)

*Edit* there were some misleading mistakes in simplified code before the answers were made. I.e. the macro had the same name of the function it replaces, this was wrong

Comment: What's wrong with just typing `object.f<typeSpecifier>()`?

Comment: Nothing, but it's not my decision.

Comment: I meant, if that is not what you're looking for, explain __why__. We can't guess what specifications you might have in mind

Comment: I could reply *What's wrong with just answering the question*, since `f.object<typeSpecifier>` is clearly not `f(object, typeSpecifier)` but that will probably bring me a downvote - (also f and f is not the same)

Comment: No really, I don't understand what you want. Do you want to write exactly `f(object, typeSpecifier)`? Do you not want to have __any__ macros? You said nothing, don't expect people to miraculously guess what you're thinking

Comment: Do you wish to call a free function named `f` with arguments `object` and `typeSpecifier`?

Comment: I had a typo in the define line, i forgot the name of the define in case someone noticed.

Comment: @PasserBy yes exactly, the question is about replacing the macro, which is used in the code base, so no typing of `object.f<typeSpecifier>()` is needed

Comment: AFAIK you can't pass a type in as an argument, its simply an error. You can wrap it around all sorts of stuff, but I don't think it makes the syntax any better.

Comment: @PasserBy So far, my trials confirm this

Comment: Types are not values. You can't use them as arguments to functions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Functions cannot take type as parameter, so you cannot do with function:

```
f(foo, int); // Not possible
```

You can wrap the type:

```
template <typename> struct tag{};

f(foo, tag<int>{});
```

but then you have to change the calling code.

So you have to keep the macro if you don't want to change the calling sites.

If you can change call sites to `f<int>(foo);`, then you may use:

```
template <typename T, typename Object>
decltype(auto) f(Object&& object)
{
    return std::forward<Object>(object).template <T>()
}
```

Comment: Acknowledged and Confirmed

Comment: This raises the question of how it could be done with the change from `f(object, MyType)` to `f<MyType>(object)`? This should be possible right?

Comment: `f<MyType>(object)` is possible, indeed, see updated answer.

Comment: Thanks, for the solution. I forgot to mention that the code is on C++98 Standard, but i extracted the problem to [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46364828/using-template-typename-in-a-nested-function-template?noredirect=1#comment79688982_46364828) since it's a different question.

Answer (score 0):

You can rely on [template argument deduction](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/template_argument_deduction) like:

```
template<typename T, typename U>
void f(T& object, const U& typeSpecifier) {
    object.template f<U>();
}
```

In this case you can call the `f` function e.g. as follows:

```
f(foo, std::string{});
```

---

As the comments below point out, my example works only for default constructable types, therefore using a helper type as shown in the [accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46362921/7893951) is a better approach:

```
template<typename>
struct type {
};

template<typename T, typename U>
void f(T& object, type<U>) {
    object.template f<U>();
}
```

Usage with [c++98](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b98):

```
int main() {
    MyType foo;
    f(foo, type<std::string>());
}
```

Comment: This does not compile

Comment: Write `object.template f<U>();`

Comment: Clever (shades of Hana).  Unfortunate that it requires default-constructibility...

Comment: @DavisHerring We get this monstrosity in the end `f(foo, std::declval<string>());`

Comment: @PasserBy: And it's so much more readable than the version where the type arguments and the value arguments are inexplicably in separate argument lists!

Comment: @DavisHerring Just realized `std::decval` won't compile. I'm dumb.

Comment: @PasserBy: Don't give up: write `f(foo,static_cast<std::string*>(nullptr));` and define the forwarding template with `U*`.

Comment: `f(foo, tag<std::string>{})` seems more natural. (or `hana::type_c` or similar).

Comment: @Jarod42, you are right and it works with types without default constructor. If you don't mind, I complemented my answer with your approach.

Answer (score 0):

A zero-overhead way would be to use tag dispatch:

```
#include <iostream>

template<class Type> struct tag {};

template<class Object, class Tag>
decltype(auto) f(Object&& o, tag<Tag>)
{
    return o.template f<Tag>();
}


struct X {
    template<class T> auto f() {
        return T(0);
    }

};

template<> auto X::f<int>() {
    std::cout << "an int" << std::endl;
    return 0;
}

template<> auto X::f<double>() {
    std::cout << "a double" << std::endl;
    return 0;
}


int main()
{
    X x;

    f(x, tag<int>());
    f(x, tag<double>());
}
```

Comment: Which funnily enough, requires more typing

Comment: Oh i will test and confirm this, but the code I am working on is C++98 standard. Sorry, i forgot to mention

Comment: @PasserBy The question is about not injecting code with a macro when a function template could be used. You don't know how often the macro is used in the code base so that comment is useless.

Comment: @tobilocker Are you migrating from a macro to a template without changing any source code? Otherwise, why would you not care about typing?

Comment: Yes exactly - so it's not about being more concise than the macro