# Using template typename in a nested function template

Tags: c++, templates, c++98

Alright, I'm struggling with templates. In [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46362227/passing-a-type-specifier-to-a-template-function) question I learned, that it is not possible to pass a type specifier to a function at all, so my next approach is passing the type inside `<>`.

Imagine a function template `foo<U>()`, which is member function of a template class `A`. So if I create an Object `A<T> a` I can call `a.foo<U>()` with any type.

How do I have to write an equivalent function template so I can pass `a` and `U` like `wrappedFoo<U>(a)`?

**IMPORTANT** Needs to be C++98 compliant

Comment: Is this the same `T` for both `A<T>` and `foo<T>`?

Comment: No could be different, maybe i should edit.

Comment: Is return type of `A<T>::foo<U>` constant (or can be computed from `T`, `U`) ? (It is the hard part before `decltype` of C++11).

Comment: I have two cases, in one case it's a plain `bool` and in the other cas it's of type `U`. Maybe for clarification: The wish (not mine) is to have a function that tests if `a` is of  type  `U`, just like Java's `isInstance`, and the othe is performing the actual cast. So the actual function being used is `QSharedPointer`'s `dynamicCast`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might do the following:

```
template <typename U, typename T>
XXXX /* See below */
WrappedFoo(/*const*/ A<T>& a)
{
    return a.template foo<U>();
}
```

The hard part is the return type without `decltype` of C++11.

So if the return type really depends of parameters type, you can create a trait, something like:

```
template <typename U, typename T>
struct Ret
{
    typedef U type;
};

template <typename T> struct Ret<T, A<T> >
struct Ret
{
    typedef bool type;
};
```

And then replace `XXXX` by `typename Ret<U, T>::type`

Comment: Alright that did it! And in my case the return type is simply `U`.